# minidlna device not showing up across 3 access points

Tags: networking, upnp

My setup is the following

1. minidlna device connected to
2. access point (dhcp server disabled) connected to
3. access point (dhcp server disabled) connected to
4. access point (dhcp server on) connected via wifi to
5. device (where I want to see the minidlna server)

All the above devices are on the same subnet 192.168.1.xxx

When I connect my device (5.) to access point at (2.) or (3.) I can see the dlna server. When I connect it to access point (4.) I cannot.

When I connect the minidlna device (server) to access point (3.) I can see the dlna server from device in access point (4.)

In general it seems that the dlna server is able to broadcast across max two access points which does not make sense to me.

I want to support the setup listed in the bullet points 1-5 above. Does anyone have any idea what goes wrong?

EDIT: minidlna http page shows up normally regardless of access point

EDIT2: all access points as well as the server are connected via ethernet. I tried also using ethernet connection for the device (5.) the results are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the access point (3.) to newer hardware and the problem solved itself. Note that access point (3.) was 100Mbps ethernet, while the others (and the new one) worked at 1Gbps. Maybe this was the culprint